Getting error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths when plotting means onto a boxplot
I am trying to plot some mean values onto a boxplot with three groups. The code I have generates the correct boxplot, but the mean values cannot be plotted. I've tried the same code for other datasets/csv files and it works fine as I have both the boxplots and the means.
Here is the code for the boxplot:
boxplot(siteD$Average_Ground ~ siteD$Sampling_Period, notch=F)

I've checked the two variables, and they are of equal lengths.
Here is the code for plotting the mean values:
meanz <- tapply(siteD$Average_Ground, siteD$Sampling_Period, mean, na.rm=T)
points(seq(1, nlevels(siteD$Sampling_Period)), meanz, 
       col = "red3", pch = 3, lwd = 2, cex = 1.2)

When trying to plot, I get the following error: Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ.
As I said, this code worked for other datasets with similar characteristics, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Hi, welcome to SO, please provide an example of your data with your code so that people can see what might be happening (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It looks like it should work, and you said it works on other data, so I'm guessing it is a problem with the data. What does meanz look like? is it the same length as number of levels in Sampling_Period?

I think this is what you are looking for
meanz <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
points(seq(1, nlevels(iris$Species)), meanz, 
       col = "red3", pch = 3, lwd = 2, cex = 1.2)

boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, notch=F)



I'm not sure why you are getting that error, but it's possible you have missing values (maybe try na.rm = FALSE).  Without seeing your data it is hard to know.
